# A/C Condenser (Outdoor) Unit Fan Squealing

Tags: hvac, noise, compressor

I think the bearings for fan in my A/C condenser unit (~10 years old) are going out...at least the high-pitched noise reminds me of a similar issue.  Here is a short vid with sound:
[Bad Bearings on my A/C Compressor?](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3mv4rlo0jjdd5qivzss7y/2023-08-12-17.55.38.mp4?rlkey=y8etojgzhq0q6ttrkuikkhe6l&dl=0)

Can anyone confirm?  Either way, is this an issue that typically DIY serviceable (e.g. some lubrication somewhere) or is a replacement required?  Unit is ~10 years old, and unfortunately, works on old type (R-22) of refrigerant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need a new compressor fan motor.

The unit does not need to be discharged of freon to be replaced. The freon lines are not even touched.

I have replaced mine a few times. It is a "nut and bolt job, but does require turning off the power to the compressor.  There should be a disconnect near the unit.

The fan specs should be on the fan itself.  The blades are removable from the shaft.  The easy way to get a new one is to take it to the AC supply store.  Or call with the make and model number info and have them look it up.

It looks like on your model the fan is suspended from the top cage.

Turn off power. Remove the cage. Remove the fan. Remove the blades.

You can trace the wires to the service panel and disconnect there, or I have had the nice people at the parts store give me weather tight connecters and I spliced the new wires to the old. (they are color coded) Tie them out of the way of the fan blades. and reinstall the blades and fan and cage in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks. The fan specs for my motor specify a rating of 1/5 HP.  I see that >>a lot<< of the replacement fans, including "universal" replacements, are 1/3 HP.  Should I care?  (nb: my condenser unit "silver tag" does not indicate motor's RPM.)

Comment: `I have replaced mine a few times` ? seriously, they last about 10 Years

Comment: If you get the plate data off the condenser we can probably look up the part# or your HVAC supply place can.

Comment: @Ruskes,  I should have qualified.   I have replaced the motors for AC units in homes that I have owned a few times.  Though I did replace the one in my personal home twice in a 30 year stretch. ( yes,  I made the AC last 33years.)

Comment: Thanks, @KMJ.  I was able to get serial and model number and contact a local HVAC parts supplier, so >>I think<< I am good to go.  Assuming replacement/hook-up, esp wire connections, goes smoothly.

Comment: @AA040371 I've had problems before where the manufacturer revised the part, but I wouldn't expect that in this case. This is a common enough part.

Comment: @KMJ: I did turn to a local HVAC supply store. I gave them my condenser unit model nbr and they gave me a "multi-HP" motor...they were nice enough to take care of wire connectors for me and toss in an extra sheet metal screw since I'd lost one.  I’ve actually never heard of a “multi-HP” motor...not quite sure what that means or implies, especially since whatever HP it may be running at, fan speed (RPM) appears to be the same (1075 RPM)…?  Motor is "The Wiz", MARS 1048, if it matters...

Comment: @AA040371 wire it different for different power levels. HVAC folks love them because they are not much more expensive and fit a bunch of applications.

Comment: @KMJ: I hope not too silly of a question: Do I actually care what HP it is wired for if RPM is same for any of the power levels?  It's odd t me since I would have expected technician to either ask me how I wanted it set for, or explain to me that it is maybe necessary to make an wiring adjustment

Comment: If you told them the model then they knew the size needed. If you wire it too high HP it will waste power, if you wire it too low power it will not run at full speed. You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Fan bearing is a DIY job if you have the right tools and knowledge.

You can start with some lubricants like wd40 or other, keeping in mind the bearing is encapsulated. However lubricating is a temporary aid. Replacing it is the best option.

Does the fan turns freely or comes to abrupt stop when power is off ?

If abrupt stop it can not be saved any more.

That unit is called Condenser. It has a compressor and the Fan.

There are 2 copper lines. Thick and thin. The thick one should be as cold as a can of beer.

Comment: Thanks.  Fan does not stop abruptly, but on other hand it only revolves about 6-7 times when system switches unit off.  I didn't think WD40 was a lubricant?

Comment: wd40 is a rust remover and lubricant

Comment: since you can not get grease in it without disassembling the bearing just use wd40

Comment: That unit is called Condenser. It has a compressor and the Fan.

There are 2 copper lines. Thick and thin. The thick one should be as cold as a can of beer.